# c# ref struct parameters inlining

Tags: c#, performance, struct, ref

I have an interesting question.

suppose we have the following functions:

```
int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;

int AddRef(ref int a, ref int b) => a + b;
```

What will be the difference if both of these functions will get inlined? (which they should if I understand correctly)
Does ref changes anything?
After all, Both Add and AddRef will be inlined to the outer scope and will be already operating on the direct variables

Full example scenario:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] // prevent Func1 from inlining
int Func1(int a, int b) => Add(a, b);

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] // prevent Func2 from inlining
int Func2(int a, int b) => AddRef(ref a, ref b);
```

**Edit:**

Did some more digging using SharpLab:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

static class Main {
    
    public static int Foo(int a, int b) => Add(a, b);
     
    public static int FooRef(int a, int b) => AddRef(ref a, ref b);
    
    public static int FooNoInline(int a, int b) => AddNoInline(a, b);    
    
    public static int FooRefNoInline(int a, int b) => AddRefNoInline(ref a, ref b);
    
    static int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;
    
    static int AddRef(ref int a, ref int b) => a + b;
    
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static int AddNoInline(int a, int b) => a + b;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static int AddRefNoInline(ref int a, ref int b) => a + b;
}
```

JIT:

```
Main.Foo(Int32, Int32)
    L0000: lea eax, [rcx+rdx]
    L0003: ret

Main.FooRef(Int32, Int32)
    L0000: lea eax, [rcx+rdx]
    L0003: ret

Main.FooNoInline(Int32, Int32)
    L0000: mov rax, Main.AddNoInline(Int32, Int32)
    L000a: jmp rax

Main.FooRefNoInline(Int32, Int32)
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0004: mov [rsp+0x30], ecx
    L0008: mov [rsp+0x38], edx
    L000c: lea rcx, [rsp+0x30]
    L0011: lea rdx, [rsp+0x38]
    L0016: call Main.AddRefNoInline(Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
    L001b: nop
    L001c: add rsp, 0x28
    L0020: ret
```

Comment: Please see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171117-00/?p=97416

Answer (score 0):

If we test your methods with this class:

```
class Main {
    public static void Foo(int a, int b) {
        var added = Add(a, b);
        Console.WriteLine(added);
    }
    
    public static void FooByRef(ref int a, ref int b) {
        var added = AddRef(ref a, ref b);
        Console.WriteLine(added);
    }
    
    static int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;

    static int AddRef(ref int a, ref int b) => a + b;
}
```

The generated assembly by the CLR's JIT compiler is this (with inlining in Release build, for x86 platform):

```
Main.Foo(Int32, Int32)
    L0000: add ecx, edx
    L0002: call System.Console.WriteLine(Int32)
    L0007: ret

Main.FooByRef(Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
    L0000: mov ecx, [ecx]
    L0002: add ecx, [edx]
    L0004: call System.Console.WriteLine(Int32)
    L0009: ret

Main.Add(Int32, Int32)
    L0000: lea eax, [ecx+edx]
    L0003: ret

Main.AddRef(Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
    L0000: mov eax, [ecx]
    L0002: add eax, [edx]
    L0004: ret
```

As we can see, the `Add` method without ref's generated smaller machine code because the method is inlined and there are no dereferencing of pointers.

In `AddRef` method which is also inlined, since we pass parameters by reference to this method with `FooRef`, there will be dereferencing involved, e.g. `[ecx]` or `[edx]`. I think the generated assembly will change if the calling method does not have `ref` parameters.

Overall, I think the method without `ref` will be faster because it will execute a single `add` instruction.

Comment: The difference in the generated JIT is interesting since AddRef gets inlined and already operates on the direct variables. I assumed it will generate the same JIT code.

Comment: @GiladFreidkin Both methods are inlined here. Generating the same JIT code for both would result in different behaviour in case the variables in question are simultaneously changed from another thread.

Comment: Yes, I think JIT has to generate this code because variables are passed by reference e.g. `Int32 ByRef`, and the value that this pointer points to can be changed by another thread as @GSerg mentioned.

Comment: @GSerg And what about a scenario when FooByRef is defined as: FooByRef(int a, int b)

Comment: Then it's not `ByRef` @GiladFreidkin. You cannot pass a `ref int` to it.

Comment: @GSerg it's a Ref to a local variable isn't it?

Comment: @GiladFreidkin No, it's not. It's a copy of the local variable's contents.

Comment: @GSerg changing `a` inside the function `AddRef` will affect it in the `FooByRef(int a, int b)` scope. Just tested it.

Comment: @GiladFreidkin Of course, if you call `AddRef` with `ref a`. That however won't change `a` in the code that calls `FooByRef(int a, int b)`.

Comment: @GSerg yea that's what I meant all along. So basically if `AddByRef` gets inlined, and the caller function DOESNT get the parameters `ByRef`, then the JIT code of the CALLER function will be the same just like as it would call `Add`